# How to decompress a .tar.xz file?

Tags: linux

There is a file having an extension .tar.xz : `wkhtmltox-linux-i386_0.12.0-03c001d.tar.xz`

What is the linux command to uncompress it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Ubuntu Site [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92328/how-do-i-uncompress-a-tarball-that-uses-xz)

```
tar -xJf wkhtmltox-linux-i386_0.12.0-03c001d.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recent version of tar (1.25 or later), you should be able to just type:

```
tar xf wkhtmltox-linux-i386_0.12.0-03c001d.tar.xz
```

And it will correctly determine what type of decompression to use.

In addition, you can use `tar caf archive.ext files_to_add` to create archives, and it will decide which compression algorithm to use based on the extension of the archive.

Answer (score 1):

The `-J, --xz` flags are for that:

```
tar -xJf file.pkg.tar.xz
```

You can also use the `xz-utils` package and use the `unxz` command on the file, then use standard `tar` from there.

Comment: you have to install xz-utils package first, and it brings unxz as a command - check if it's available in your distro repository via your package manager.

Comment: actually checking in Ubuntu - it's installed by default. I suppose if it's not installed, the tar command won't work with the -J,--xz flags.